# How two sum different form with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code sum selected option:

```
function validate(){
  var $selected = $('#mark, #series').children(":selected");
  var sum = 0;

  $selected.each(function() {
    sum += $(this).data('price') || 0;
  });

  $('#total').html(sum === 0 ? '' : sum + '$');
}
validate();

$('#mark, #series').on('change', function() {
  validate();
});


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<select id="mark" name="mark">
          <option value="">--</option>
          <option value="bmw" data-price="200">bmw</option>
          <option value="audi" data-price="400">audi</option>
        </select>

<select id="series" name="series">
          <option value="">--</option>
          <option value="series-1" data-price="2000"  >3 series</option>
          <option value="series-1" data-price="3000"  >5 series</option>
        </select>

<div id="total"> </div>
</form>
```

i want add another form and do sum for other  selected option.

```
   function validate(){
```

how edit this line and do that one js code work for form1 and other js code fror other form2

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your `validate()` function reads a fixed set of `select` elements (#mark and #series). If you want to read additional element you have to either modify the `validate` function to add the new element (not recommended!) or make it independent of the specific ids of the select elements: use a css class to get the elements you want to sum instead of theirs ids.

Here is an example:

```js
function validate() {
  var $selected = $('.sum-item').children(":selected");
  var sum = 0;

  $selected.each(function() {
    sum += $(this).data('price') || 0;
  });

  $('#total').html(sum === 0 ? '' : sum + '$');
}
validate();

$('.sum-item').on('change', function() {
  validate();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="mark" name="mark" class="sum-item">
          <option value="">--</option>
          <option value="bmw" data-price="200">bmw</option>
          <option value="audi" data-price="400">audi</option>
        </select>

  <select id="series" name="series" class="sum-item">
          <option value="">--</option>
          <option value="series-1" data-price="2000"  >3 series</option>
          <option value="series-1" data-price="3000"  >5 series</option>
        </select>

  <select id="other" name="series" class="sum-item">
          <option value="">--</option>
          <option value="type-a" data-price="10"  >Type A</option>
          <option value="type-b" data-price="20"  >Type B</option>
          <option value="type-c" data-price="30"  >Type C</option>
        </select>

  <div id="total"> </div>
</form>
```